# No error message in C++ class header file when curly brace is missing at the end of class definition?

Tags: c++

I just spent the past two hours trying to figure out why I had so many error messages in my program, and it turned out that I had forgotten to add a closing brace at the end of one of my class header files. So my question is: Why did I not get any error messages about this issue in my header file, given that I got a crapload of messages about the errors that had occurred as a result of that missing brace in my *other* project files? If someone could please explain this to me in terms that a beginner could understand that would be great :)

Cheers

Comment: because you included that header file into some source file and this is done before the actual compilation takes place. If the closing bracket is missing, there is no way for the compiler to know where your class definition is supposed to end (as in principle it might be spread over many files including each other). Tip: Use a IDE that shows you missing brackets already while typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I suppose you defined several classes, like this example :

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    void do_something();
// missing };

class B
{
  public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}
    void do_something_other();
};
```

When the compiler start reading the description of the class B, there is no error to notice because your class B is viewed as a nested class, like in this correct example :

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    void do_something();

    class B
    {
      public:
        B() {}
        ~B() {}
        void do_something_other();
    };
};
```

Then, it's impossible for the compiler to exaclty know what you want to do, and which class is nested or not.

Of course, at a moment, you have an error. At least on the number of closing braces. But more probably when a part of your code is forbidden inside the class description. It's why the error can be verry strange.

Answer (score 3):

yes, it happens. Include files are just text, they don't need to contain a valid self-contained code. you can think of `#include`s as copy-paste. you could have

main.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
```

a.h

```
int main() {
```

b.h

```
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: you might add a note, that this is completely legal but not at all recommended (unless participating in an code obfuscation contest)